# Coderbyte Letter Changes - wrong changes

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I was solving the Letter Changes challenge on Coderbyte which goes as follows:

> Have the function LetterChanges(str) take the str parameter being passed and modify it using the following algorithm.
>
> Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a).
>
> Then capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and finally return this modified string.

But I don't know why the portion of my code that changes the letters with the next one in the alphabet doesn't work correctly. Here's the code:

```
function LetterChanges(str){
    for(var i in str){
        if(str.charAt(i).match(/[a-y]/i)) 
           str = str.replace(str.charAt(i),String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i) + 1));
        else if(str.charAt(i).match(/z/i))
           str = str.replace(str.charAt(i),"a");
    }
    // the code to capitalize vowels follows
    return str;
}
  LetterChanges("Argument goes here") //outputs "Btivpfnu hofs hfsf" instead of "Bshvnfou hpft ifsf"
```

Comment: You didn't type `dog`, did you?

Comment: Just in case, this is [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ezedcLzy/).

Comment: I don't understand @Ayo, your code works.

Comment: @Andy, Yeah. I know the code should work. But when I run LetterChanges("Argument goes here"), I get "Btivpfnu hofs hfsf", instead of "Bshvnfou hpft ifsf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've figured out why your code is causing you problems - took me a while to work out what was going on tho :)

This is your problem line:

```
str = str.replace(str.charAt(i), String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i) + 1));
```

In the console you can see what's happening if you log the output of `str` after that replace.

At first everything goes well:

```
Brgument goes herez
Bsgument goes herez
Bshument goes herez
Bshvment goes herez
Bshvnent goes herez
Bshvnfnt goes herez
Bshvofnt goes herez
Bshvofnu goes herez
Bshvofnu hoes herez
Bshvpfnu hoes herez
Bshvpfnu hofs herez
```

Until you get to here.

```
Bthvpfnu hofs herez
```

What's happening is that when it tries to change the "s" at the end of "goes" `str.charAt(i)` is equal to "s", but the replace simply does what it's meant to do: change the *first* "s" in `str` to a `t`, which is also why it doesn't change that second "s" to a "t".

```
Btivpfnu hofs herez
...
```

Everyone here has given you an answer to how you can recode, but this is specifically *why* your code doesn't work. Hope that helps.

---

Not specifically an answer to your question, but an alternative way of solving the problem:

```
function letterChanges(str) {

  // put the string into lowercase (not sure if you need to do this
  // but it makes sense if you only want the vowels in uppercase
  // and then split the string into an array and use `map` to...
  return str.toLowerCase().split('').map(function (el, i) {

    // swap the letters
    var swap = el !== 'z' ? String.fromCharCode(el.charCodeAt(0) + 1) : 'a';

    // and then return the letter, changing it to uppercase if it's
    // a vowel. Finally return the joined array
    return /[aeiou]/g.test(swap) ? swap.toUpperCase() : swap;
  }).join('');
}

letterChanges('Andz'); // bOEA
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rha57gfe/)

Comment: thanks. But the issue is that I want to understand why my code gives "Btivpfnu hofs hfsf" as output when I run LetterChanges("Argument goes here") instead of "Bshvnfou hpft ifsf"

Comment: Wooow! Thanks so much for spotting that. You actually just revealed what cost me two 2 days of headache. I'll change my logic then.But one more question plsss..., why doesn't the letter 'o' in 'goes' change to 'p' as desired? Thanks.

Comment: @Ayo, the best advice I can give you is to use your console more and mark breakpoints so you can follow the code through. Glad to help.

Comment: Oh, and instead of using `match` look at `test` instead.

Comment: @Ayo, because a character "m" has already been changed to "o", and so that gets changed again instead of the other "o". Same logic.

Comment: Oops! Thanks so much @Andy. Probably changing each charater by calling the `replace()` method on the whole string isn't a good approach. I'll try to see how to use `test()` method in solving it but I don't know how to use it yet.

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't know why the portion of my code that changes the letters
>   with the next one in the alphabet

Solution with regex :

```
function setNextWithVowels(str)
{  str=str.toLowerCase();
   return  str.replace(/([a-z])/g,function(m,g){ 
    var c=g.charCodeAt();
    var nxt=String.fromCharCode(c==122?c-25:c+1);
    return   /[aeiou]/g.test(nxt) ? nxt.toUpperCase():nxt;});
}

 console.log(setNextWithVowels("abz")) //bcA
```

---

Another method to set next letter for individual :

```
function getNextchar(c)
{
 var a='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' , len = a.length;
 return  a.substr((a.indexOf(c) + 1) % len  ,1) 
}

alert(getNextchar('x')); //y
alert(getNextchar('z')); //a
```

Comment: I have edited my question so you can know what my actual problem is. I've added the output when I run the code with coderbyte's supplied argument. Thanks.

Comment: @Ayo No. you should get according to your question : `bshvnfOU hpft Ifsf` I edited.

Comment: hmm.. yeah, you're right. I know my code should give that but probably for some reasons I don't know, those that passed the challenge had that output as their solution. What is even bothering me is why my own code is giving the incorrect output it's giving, instead of the output you correctly stated that it should give. Can you help me debug it?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this code:

```
function LetterChanges(str){
    var output = "";
    for(var i in str){
        if(str.charAt(i) == 'z') {
            output += 'a';
        }
        else {
           output += String.valueOf((str.charAt(i) + 1));
        }
    }
    // the code to capitalize vowels follows
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my problem is that I don't know why my code gives "Btivpfnu hofs hfsf", instead of "Bshvnfou hpft ifsf". Can you help me check it out?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are over-complicating this a bit.

The approach is:

- Replace every letter by…:

  - if it’s a “z” or a “Z”: an “a” or an “A” (`offset` `-25`)
  - otherwise by the next letter (`offset` `1`)

```
function LetterChanges(str){
  str=str.replace(/[a-z]/gi,function(letter){
    var offset=1;
    if(letter.toLowerCase()=='z'){
      offset=-25;
    }
    return String.fromCharCode(letter.charCodeAt()+offset);
  });

  // code to capitalize vowels here

  return str;
}
LetterChanges('abczABCZ'); // bcdaBCDA
```

Comment: thanks. But the issue is that I want to understand why my code gives "Btivpfnu hofs hfsf" as output  when I run LetterChanges("Argument goes here") instead of "Bshvnfou hpft ifsf".

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the `match` function in your code, to do a global search:

```
if (str.charAt(i).match(/[a-y]/g))
```

Fix that little bit and your code will be correct for changing each letter correctly.

Now to finish the capitalization of vowels...